# Is there a public google calendar api key?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'd like to share an example and code of a custom calendar app that I made using a google calendar api V3 feed, but I'd rather not show my calendar with my api key. Is there a public google calendar and api key?

Answer (score 0):

The Google API key does not belong to a unique service such as Google Calendar API, it applies to all services activated with your account.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of a public api key for testing where google calendar is enabled?

Comment: @approots here you can activate the google calender from here and get the key you want, https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:548657163732:services, you can Generate new key and if you don't use the Google API Key.

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather not show my calendar with my api key. I can see why google wouldn't offer a public key since it could get overwhelmed. Thanks anyway.